# Xcode Expected a type Parse issue when importing Swift Framework into Objective C app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I am having a very strange issue when importing a Swift Framework into an objective-c project.  The project fails to build. I get a Parse Issue with message "Expected Type" originating from the MyFramework-Swift-h file that Xcode generates.  The warning is specifically on the signature for a method which accepts a typed array as its single parameter.

The swift method looks like this:

```
@objc public func set(paymentMethods: [PaymentMethod]) -> ParamsBuilder {
    params.paymentMethods = paymentMethods
    return self
}
```

And once compiled it looks like this:

```
- (ParamsBuilder * _Nonnull)setWithPaymentMethods:(NSArray<PaymentMethod *> * _Nonnull)paymentMethods SWIFT_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT;
```

The Parse Issue is complaining about the NSArray type, which it doesn't seem to understand.  Very oddly I found a horribly hack fix which doesn't actually help in the long run.  In the MyFramework-Swift-h file, there is a block towards the top:

```
#if __has_feature(modules)
@import ObjectiveC;
#endif
```

If I manually add @import UIKit, the Objective C project will now compile.  I can't however figure out how XCode determines what to automatically import.  My Framework imports UIKit in lots of places, so it seems strange that its not imported.  I also have no idea why importing it manually helps find the NSArray type!

Answer (score 0):

NSArray is a Foundation collection object, not UIKit. UIKit includes Foundation via other headers (NSDataAsset.h), so you are seeing the result of NSArray being recognized.

As an example, this is from the AudioKit's header file for Swift - ObjectiveC interoperability:

```
//
//  AudioKit.h
//  AudioKit
//
//  Created by Aurelius Prochazka, revision history on Github.
//  Copyright © 2018 AudioKit. All rights reserved.
//
#pragma once

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#if !TARGET_OS_TV
#import <CoreAudioKit/CoreAudioKit.h>
#endif
```

Seems like your generated header file might have no idea what is going on as the import is missing, you need to tell it what is needed. You might have deleted the line accidentally, or the header files was generated without it. So, either

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

or

```
import Foundation
```

must be used to tell the header you want NS* objects defined.

Your framework can include UIKit in multiple places, yet auto-generated header might not have the methods defined in it (functions are missing @objc, etc). So, import statement might be passed out.